# full text search using sql server 2008

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2008-express

I had installed sql server 2008 express edition with tools but I need to use full text search which i understand is missing in the edition that I have.

How do I go about upgrading to get full text search feature? As it was an online installation I don't have any installation media stored on my computer

Can I use something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a downloadable version of SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Advanced Tools which does include full text indexing. Freely downloadable from Microsoft web site.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b5d1b8c3-fda5-4508-b0d0-1311d670e336&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3):

You should run "SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Advanced Tools" installation and specify "configure existing installation" option.